# Dynamic meta tags issue in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering, meta-tags

I am fetching blog data from mysql. Now I want to show meta tags title, description but reacl-helmet not working. I have tride razzle react app but everything failed. Any idea how to do it?

```
{storyInfo.story.map((story, index) =>
                <OgData
                    title={story.title}
                    description={story.body.substring(0, 100)} url={`http://fnmotivation.com/post/` + story.story_id + "/" + story.title.replace(/\s/g, '-').substring(0, 60)}
                    image={`http://fnmotivation.com/${story.post_thumbnail}`} />)}

    <Helmet>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>{title}</title>
        <meta name="title" content={title} />
        <meta name="description" content={description} />
        <meta property="og:title" content={title} />
        <meta property="og:image" content={image} />
        <meta property="og:description" content={description} />
        <meta property="og:url" content={url} />
    </Helmet>
```

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to this? I just ran into the same problem.

Comment: No man. I tried everything but no solution found yet. If you find one please let me know.

Comment: Have you ever tried to do server side rendering? I think that might be able to fix it, but I didn't have a chance to test it yet.

Comment: I did that but no results.